# Blackberry RRT signing problem!

Tags: blackberry, signing

Gurus, I got the keys from RIM to sign my application, however, the signing tool won't sign the RRT, I'm succesfully signing the RCR but not the RRT so the application won't run on a device, I'm getting this error that speaks for it's self:
[alt text http://www.techlocus.com/blackberry/problem.png](http://www.techlocus.com/blackberry/problem.png)

I'm using Eclipse with the plugin 1.1. JRE 5.0.0.

Any help would be appreciated, if you need more information please let me know

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I googled the problem for a while and found nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIM sends back your signing keys as three separate emails (RCR, RRT, and RBB) - make sure that you clicked on the attachment for all three of them to register them on your computer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I only had to do the process for one file, I did it for RCR and that's why it got signed. Now I signed on all of them.